# transition branch to be master with git

Tags: git, ruby-on-rails-3, workflow, git-branch

I've converted an application from Rails 3.0 to 3.1.3 and have it on a branch.  I would like to transition the rails 3.1.3 branch to be the new master and a merge doesn't make sense to me.  What's the best way to do this?

**Update**

I explained this wrong.  I moved to Rails 3.1.3 from 3.0 by creating a new rails projects and moving things over since Rails 3.1 is quite a big change in directory structure, etc.  Right now they are actually in two different repositories but I don't want to lose history and abandon the old repository.  I'd rather have the Rails 3.1.3 version as the master of the old repository and move the 3.0 version to another branch and eliminate the need for multiple repositories.

Comment: What do you mean a merge doesn't make sense? Maybe you want `git merge -s theirs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to make the 3.1.3 branch as master

```
git branch -m master 3.0rails
git branch -m 3.1.3rails master
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have **Not** pushed it at all, you can (make sure you have the latest of master first):

git checkout mybranchWithRails3.1.3
git rebase master

What it will do, is replay all the changes on top of master and move the head of your branch to it.

Then you can:

git checkout master
git merge mybranchWithRails3.1.3

It will fast forward, so it'll be like if you never had it in a branch. Again, make sure to have the latest first, so you're not forced into pulling changes and it auto merging while doing that (can fix, but much easier not even having to do that)

Comment: it's different though, these are not changes on top of master.  i took the approach of starting a new rails 3.1 project and moving everything over (there entire directory structure is different).  it's a big diff